# Chrome bug in svg getScreenCTM

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, svg

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dpLrwpov/7/)

I try to use the `getScreenCTM` function for retrive the position of the mouse based on SVG image coordinate. In IE and Firefox it works, but in Chrome doesn't.

If I define the attributes `width` and `heigth` in the SVG element and next I change it with CSS it seems that `getScreenCTM` give me back always the unscaled matrix (based on inline size?).

Summary:

[image: getScreenCTM()]

I have made some error? Or it's a Chrome bug?

Comment: tested on IE11 and FF31 and the jsFiddle works

Comment: This bug is fixed as of Chrome 38.0.2125.104 m (released 2014-10-14)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I filed this bug after hitting the same issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402790

See the repro:
http://jsbin.com/lexid/3/edit

The issue was introduced in Chrome 36.

The fix is currently in Chrome 39.  It may get merged into a Chrome 38 update.  So we will have a fix mid November when Chrome 39 moves to the stable channel or before if it makes it into 38.

Unfortunately I've also seen this same issue on my iPhone since I've updated to iOS 8 - both in Safari and Chrome.

UPDATE: Here is a monkey patch for this bug:
http://jsbin.com/motaqi/1/edit

UPDATE 2: This bug is now fixed as of Chrome 38.0.2125.104 m (released 2014-10-14)

Answer (score 0):

Possible due to this Chrome bug? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402790 or perhaps this one? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81995

Comment: I think it's the first one.